# clarification to specific solution of the first order linear PDE problem $4u_{x}-3u_{y}=0, u(0,y)=y^3$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am analyzing the following first order PDE problem and have difficulties with understanding the solution

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
4u_{x}-3u_{y}=0\\ 
u(0,y)=y^3
\end{matrix}\right.$$

I understand how the general solution is derived which is 
$$u(x,y)=f(c)=f(-3x-4y)$$
from the boundary condition  we know that
$$u(0,y)=f(-4y)=y^3$$
That's all clear so far.

I don't understand the following steps and especially the last substitution (w for 3x+4y). Can anybody clarify the logic behind those substitutions?

$$w=-4y$$
$$-\frac{1}{64} w^3 = y^3$$
$$f(w)=-w^3/64$$
$$u(x,y)=(3x+4y)^3/64$$

is it a trick with the substitution here or more a systematic way of solving this type of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obtain the general solution $u(x,y)=f(-3x-4y)$ which is correct.

Then , with the boundary condition, you obtained $f(-4y)=y^3$ which is correct.

This relationship defines the function $f(X)$

$f(X)=y^3 \text{ where } X=-4y \quad\to\quad y=-\frac{X}{4} \quad\to\quad f(X)=\left(-\frac{X}{4}\right)^3$
$$f(X)= -\frac{X^3}{4^3}$$

Thus :
$$u(x,y)=f(-3x-4y)=f(X) \text{ where } X=-3x-4y$$
$$u(x,y)=f(X)=-\frac{X^3}{4^3}=-\frac{(-3x-4y)^3}{4^3}$$ 
$$u(x,y)=\frac{(3x+4y)^3}{64}$$